# Given a space what spaces can it cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was thinking about my previous question and thought about going the other way around. Assume we are given a space $Y$ and $Y$ covers $X$, then how much can be said about $X$? The most trivial property would be that if $Y$ is compact, then $X$ would also be compact. In other words, I would like to classify all spaces that a particular space can cover.

Lets pick for example the unit disk $D^1$. Assuming $D^1\to X$ is a cover and $X$ is a CW-complex, then the Euler characteristics gives $\chi(D^1)=1$, so $\chi(X)=1$. The classification theorem would then imply that $X\approx D^1$, since the universal cover of a simply-connected space is just itself.

The second easiest example is probably $\mathbb{C}P^2$. Now the Euler characteristic is $2$, so if it covers a CW-complex $X$, then simple-connectivity would force the cover to have degree $1$ or $2$. In the first case, we would just have the space itself. If the cover has degree $2$ I'm not completely sure what to do, since the only thing we seem to know is that $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}_2?$

If we drop the assumption that $X$ is a CW-complex, then can anything meaningful be said except that higher homotopy groups are equal?

Comment: From a prior question, any covering map from $D^n$ is a homeomorphism: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94936/covering-map-on-the-unit-disk

Comment: Based on the proof given there, it would then suffice to show that any homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}P^2\to \mathbb{C}P^2$ has a fixed point, since that would show that the fundamental group of $X$ must be trivial (equals group of deck transformations) and the cover would have to have just 1-sheet. Do we always know such a map has a fixed point?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that that proof would extend to $\mathbb CP^2$, only that it covered the $D^n$ case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You don't have to imply it, since it does extend. ;) The only thing we need is to show that the fundamental group is trivial which forces the number of sheets to be $1$. This clearly follows if the group of deck transformations is trivial, which is the method of proof that was used in that question.

Comment: Finding such a fixed point seems to follow from the Lefshetz fixed-point theorem... It seems like my two examples are then covered. How much can be said about the general case? Any other strategies to deduce information about the base space?

Comment: As a general rule, if memory serves me, coverings by a space $X$ correspond to discrete (closed?) subgroups, $G$, of $Aut(X)$ in which no element other than the identity has a fixed point.  Then the coverings are of the form $X/G$. However, then you have the question of when $X\rightarrow X/G$ is equivalent to $X\rightarrow X/H$.  Clearly this is true if $H$ is a conjugate of $G$, for example.

Comment: (I think my condition on $G$ needs tweaking.)